# Modifying data stored in SQLite Database - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an activity (CreateLine) which you can see below in a screenshot. When the user fills out this screen and click on the green button the data is successfully saving to my SQLite Database. Although, now I would like the user to be able to go back to the CreateLine screen and edit or update the existing data that they previously stored. I am using a database helper with all of database functions in it.

Due to the fact that the insertdata() function was adding the data correctly I thought I should just copy and paste this code to a new function called Updatedata() but I don't think this works. I am not quite sure where to go from here.

Database functions from DatabaseHelper:

```
 public boolean insertData(String linetype, String packagetype, String quantity, String duration, String starttime, String endtime) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, linetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, packagetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, duration);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, starttime);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, endtime);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

 public boolean updateData(String linetype, String packagetype, String quantity, String duration, String starttime, String endtime) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, linetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, packagetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_5, duration);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, starttime);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, endtime);
    long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, null, null );
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

CreateLine Class (code behind verify or green button):

```
VerifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String spinnerSelection = String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
            String spinnerSelection2 = String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem());
            String q = quantity.getText().toString();
            String d = duration.getText().toString();

            DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(yearNow, monthNow, dayNow, hourNow, minuteNow);
            DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");
            String formattedtime = fmt.print(dateTime);
            CalculateButton.setText(formattedtime);

            // Plus some hours, minutes, and seconds to the original DateTime.
            DateTimeFormatter fmt2 = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E d MMM yyyy" + "\n" + " h:mm a ");

            DateTime dateTime1 = dateTime.plusHours(timeadded);
            String endtimecalc = fmt2.print(dateTime1);
            TextView endtime = (TextView) findViewById(endtimetextView);
            endtime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            endtime.setText(endtimecalc);


            //INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(
                    spinnerSelection,
                    spinnerSelection2,
                    q,
                    d,
                    formattedtime,
                    endtimecalc);


            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(CreateLine.this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            boolean isUpdated = myDb.updateData(
                        spinnerSelection,
                        spinnerSelection2,
                        q,
                        d,
                        formattedtime,
                        endtimecalc);
            if (isUpdated == true)
                Toast.makeText(CreateLine.this, "Data Successfully updated!" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Screenshot of CreateLine Activity:

[image: CreateLine]

I am thinking I might need some sort of IF statement to check whether or not data already exists before using the update function?

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: where you call `updateData()`?

Comment: if you can see where I have commented //UPDATE DATA, the line below that then I pass the strings to be updated

Comment: Why `updateData` method is **exactly** the same as `insertData`, it even calls `db.insert` ???

Comment: oh yes that needs changed to update! do you think that's the problem or?

Comment: I have updated the update function above

Comment: Thats better but I don't understand why at first you perform an insert operation and immediately after an update with the same values. Also you don't provide the conditions upon the `update`, on which saved row you want to update, there should be a `where` statement (the 3rd parameter in the `update` method)

Comment: When the update or insert method get called? When button is clicked ?

Comment: I suppose what I am trying to do is that if there is no data In a row, say my primary key is B1, then add the data. if there is data then once the user re-enters data and the green button is clicked, it updates the changes.

Comment: Yes @JohnJoe on the click of the verify or green button that you can see

Comment: But where is the `onClick` ?

Comment: I have updated the code @JohnJoe

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the data is exists or not. If no, then do insert, Otherwise update data.

**Example in onClick**

```
boolean check = doesDataExist(spinnerSelection,spinnerSelection2,q,d,formattedtime,endtimecalc);

  if(check==true)  // data exists
     {
       myDb.updateData(spinnerSelection,spinnerSelection2, q, d, formattedtime, 
      endtimecalc);  // updata data
     }
   else
   {
      myDb.insertData(spinnerSelection, spinnerSelection2,q,d, 
      formattedtime,endtimecalc); // insert data
    }
```

And here the example to check whether data is existing

```
  public boolean doesDataExist(String spinnerSelection,..,..,..,..,..){
    final String query = "SELECT stationName FROM review WHERE stationId='"+name+"' LIMIT 1";  // write query here
         SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor c = database.rawQuery(query, null)) {
        return c.moveToFirst();
    }
```

Comment: If I have a primary key which distinguishes each row, like B1 for row 1 and B2 for row 2.. do I need to write separate functions for each row or how can I pass the primary key so that it knows which row to update?

Comment: In the `if(check == true)`, you can create another function to retrieve the primary key. Once you get the ID , you can pass to `updateData` function, and it will be `myDb.updateData(ID,spinnerSelection,spinnerSelection2, q, d, formattedtime, 
      endtimecalc);`

Comment: To get the query, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14017956/5156075

Comment: the first spinnerselection is the primary key field

Comment: ok, so your problem is ? You don't know the update query or what ?